# BigQuery Table Compression

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have check the compression format in BigQuery table.

Do you know any optimization technique for BigQuery table storage?

Thanks,
Anand C

Comment: Are you asking about compressing data exported from BigQuery ... https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#loading_compressed_and_uncompressed_data

If not and are asking if we can compress the data that is stored inside BigQuery itself to reduce our storage costs ... I don't believe there is a way to do that.  When we look at pricing, there are no mentions of compression.  In fact, the documentation explains how to project your costs based on byte sizes for fields ... https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing

Comment: Thank you for sharing.As pricing for big query based on the byte sizes for fields. Looks the documentation explains only the byte cost. I am looking for other options in GCP to enable faster query.

Comment: @Anand can you clarify in your quesiton if you are asking how to optimize storage costs, or how to optimize query speed and costs?

Comment: @kolban Hi Neil, data in BQ storage is actually compressed already but it is charged uncompressed. In Q1 of 2022 (so that's now), it should become possible to negotiate a rate based on the compressed data volume. This is called "BQ Compressed Storage". For BQ users with multiple PBs of storage, this should amount to very signficant savings.

Comment: @Paul, do you have references to BQ compressed Storage as mentioned above. Is this discretionary by Google or BAU. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check BigQuery best practices in Google Cloud Platform [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs).

There you will be able to see some tips as:

> **- Avoid SELECT  ***
>
> **- Don't run queries to explore or preview table data**
>
> **- Before running queries, preview them to estimate costs**
>
> **- Use the maximum bytes billed setting to limit query costs**

Comment: The question in my understanding was more related to the storage side of the costs in BQ rather than on the query side of the costs.

Comment: @LeonardoCampos Hi, thanks for your comment. You can also check those details as ["Partition data by date"](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#partition_data_by_date) in the docuemntation I mentioned. I hope this can be helpful for you.